# Installed JavaFX but can't use it on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javafx

I have installed JavaFX from https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/

I have Eclipse SDK Version: 2019-12 (4.14) and Java SDK 13, running on Windows 10.

I have added Jar files via Preferences on Eclipse as seen in ScreenShot:

[image]

I have then right-clicked on the project path -- Build Path --> Add library --> user libraries --> and then selected JavaFX and added it to the path as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

When I click run I get this error: 
"Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application"

Why does this appear?

Comment: Are you following https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Eclipse?

Comment: @JoséPereda Yes I did follow the procedure from that link. But I got that message. In that link it says "you get that message because you lack javafx.graphics". But I do have javafx.graphics.

Comment: Did you add the VM arguments?

Comment: @JoséPereda yes I did it now and now I don't get that message anymore. But now I get `java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <<> at index 9: C:\Users\<user>\Downloads\javafx-sdk-11\lib`.  The path is wrong, I didn't download the sdk files on "Downloads". Do you know how to change it?

Comment: Did you use _your own path_?

Comment: @JoséPereda yes, the jar files are in C:\Program Files\Utils\JavaFX\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the VM arguments that you have added?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208131/discussion-between-coder88-and-jose-pereda).

Comment: @JoséPereda I just used this `--module-path "C:\Program Files\Utils\JavaFX\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls` as VM arguments (right-click the project --> Run As --> Run configurations --> Arguments --> in the VM arguments box. I just had to put quotes becaues the path has spaces. It works now. Thanks for your help.